# Celery + rabbitmq RPC result return failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery, rpc

I'm using **Celery 5.2.7** + **rabbitmq 3.9-management** for RPC. My applications are separated into 3 different containers: **worker**, **rabbitmq**, and **API** which makes RPC call.

All containers are deployed via single docker-compose and connected to a `bridge` network. Whole cluster works on a single machine under **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**.

Work scenario is the following:

1. API receives request from user
2. API puts a job for gpu worker to rabbitmq and waits for response.
3. GPU worker listens to task queue and performs computations when the new task occurs
4. When computations are complete, GPU worker sends results back (via another rabbitmq queue, I suppose)

**My problem is that API never gets its results back. As I can see in logs, my gpu worker gets the job done in <0.1 seconds, but my API never gets results**

***Setup:***

Worker:

```py
#celery_worker.py
app = Celery('celery_worker', broker= f'amqp://{rabbitmq_username}:{rabbitmq_password}@{rabbitmq_host}:{rabbitmq_port}/', backend='rpc://')

@app.task
def remote_procedure(a, b):
    #some heavy computations
    return res
```

API main:

```py
#API main.py
from proj.celery_worker import remote_procedure

RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 1.5

@app.get('/search/') 
def search(a,b):
    try:
        res = remote_procedure.apply_async((a,b), expires = RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS-0.3, retry=False).get(timeout=RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
    except celery.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')
        return {"res":"timeout"}
    return {"res":res}


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=CONFIG['port'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Compose:

```yaml
 gpu_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.worker
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 10gb
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [ gpu ]
    networks:
      - search_net
  
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    depends_on:
      - gpu_worker
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    environment:
      MAX_WORKERS: 32
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 10gb
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [ gpu ]
    networks:
      - search_net

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - rabbitmq_log:/var/log/rabbitmq/
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - search_net

volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
  rabbitmq_log:

networks:
  search_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile.worker:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "celery", "-A", "proj.celery_worker", "worker", "--loglevel=DEBUG", "--pool=solo", "-c", "1"]
```

Dockerfile.api:

```
...
EXPOSE 80

# Start the app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

I'm not setting any other params, so all other parameters or configurations must be default.

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that there is some kind of trouble with returning results. Is it possible that there are networking troubles inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

It was a `celery` problem. `RPC` result backend with `rabbit` is still bugged and sometimes loses results. I've used `redis` backend for results instead, and it worked.